# An Asimov short story about the death of an alien with many hearts

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, isaac-asimov

This one, you would think I could just google, but it did not work. I tried various combinations of keywords, but to no avail.

Also the box that just opened to suggest duplicates does not address it.

I must have read it in a collection, more than 20 years ago or so, but I can’t remember exactly when or what the book looked like, or what others stories were there (there are sooooo many Asimov collections, plus collections with various authors including stories by the Good Doctor).

It is one of Asimov’s short stories just for the sake of a bad pun. But I completely forgot anything except that it was about the death of an alien with many hearts, and that I did not understand the joke at all (but I am french, so I must have lacked the context).

I know I should have investigated then, when it was still fresh in my memory, but I was too lazy. Maybe it is not too late to make amends...

Edit: I just tried to google it once more, and I was surprised to get an answer in a StackExchange page.... but it was a link to this page here !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Asimov's [*Death of a Foy*,](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49660) also featured in [this Stack Exchange Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2878) question.

> "Give my big hearts to Maude, Dwayne. Dismember me for Harold's choir. Tell all the Foys in Sortibackenstrete that I will soon be there --"

Comment: The explanation of the pun is in that link ! Thanks a lot, it did not mean anything to me at that time.

Comment: @Alfred The fact that he messed up the pun probably didn't help.

Comment: By "messed up" do you mean that "Foys" rhymes with "boys" while the song had "gang" and not "boys", as I just found out ? For me it wouldn't have changes a thing... I never heard of that song at that time anyway :D